# listar registros agrupados por mes y ordenarlos en forma cronológica en mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

que tal tengo un problemita:

Estoy intentando mostrar los registros de una tabla ordenados por mes, pero el orden lo necesito de forma cronológico, Tengo un campo en la tabla llamado "mes" en donde ingreso los nombres del mes según la necesidad

Esto es lo que necesito mostrar:

```
Enero:
-doc1
-doc2
Febrero:
-doc1
-doc2
Marzo:
-doc1
-doc2
```

y así sucesivamente.

Actualmente tengo esta consulta:

```
<?php 
            $consulta_A = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM articulo8 WHERE fraccion = 'VI'AND inciso ='Inciso H' AND ano = '2017' ORDER BY mes DESC") or die("Error en consulta Agenda".mysqli_error($con));

              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_A)) {
                $documento = $row["documento"];                  
                 $año = $row["ano"];
                 $mes = $row["mes"];
                 $ruta = $row["ruta"];
                 $departamento = $row["departamento"];
                  ?>                    
                <ul><?php echo $mes; ?>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo "plataformadetransparencia/".$ruta.$documento; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $departamento; ?></a></li> 
                </ul>
          <?php  } ?>
```

Pero el resultado que me muestra es este:

```
Septiebre:
-doc1
Septiembre:
-doc1
Octubre:
-doc1
Octubre:
-doc2
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar

Comment: El query esta perfecto. tu problema es la vista.. trabaja sobre ella.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una forma de resolverlo, también puedes usar bloques `if else` o case si te pones creativo. También me parece que no es necesario asignar una variable para cada campo del `fetch` dado que ya estás asignando esa variable en tu bloque `while` de esta manera `$row = mysqli_fetch_array()`.

```
<?php 
  $consulta_A = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM articulo8 WHERE fraccion = 'VI'AND inciso ='Inciso H' AND ano = '2017' ORDER BY mes DESC") or die("Error en consulta Agenda".mysqli_error($con));

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_A)) {

    echo ($mes == $row["mes"] ? '' : '<ul>' . $row["mes"] )
        .' <li><a href="plataformadetransparencia/' . $row["ruta"] . $row["documento"] . '" target="_blank">' . $row["departamento"] . '</a></li>'
        . ($mes == $row["mes"] ? '' : '</ul>');
    $mes = $row["mes"];
  }
```

Comment: Hola @Solrac, parece funcionar pero no del todo... Me imprime varios numeros "1" entre cada < li >. se muestra asi:    Enero: 1 doc1 11 doc2 11 doc2 11 doc4 1

Comment: Está imprimiendo todos los `true` resultado de las operaciones ternarias. Actualicé mi ejemplo para imprimir mensajes en blanco en su lugar.